# L20n translate the placeholder/attribute from textarea and input field

Tags: localization, l20n

How to localize the placeholder from textarea or input?
If i use the following example it puts the translation direct as text into the textarea.

```
...
<textarea name="message" rows="20" cols="30" placeholder="Message" data-l10n-id="Message"></textarea>
...
```

Language File

```
...
   <Message "Foo Bar">
...
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Localize an attribute with l20n](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29329204/localize-an-attribute-with-l20n)

Comment: @JohnKiller doesn't work for me.

Comment: also post you language file please

Comment: read again my answer on the question i linked you. your language file is missing the attribute name, like i've explained

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your language file should be

```
<Message placeholder:"Foo Bar">
```

You need to specify wich attribute to translate. Given your HTML, setting the attribute `placeholder="Message"` is not needed.