# Localize an attribute with l20n

Tags: html, localization, internationalization, attributes, l20n

I'd like to localize a `placeholder` attribute with L20N. I can't find anything in their documentation, and doing this (unsurprisingly) doesn't work.

```
<input type="text" data-l10n-id="email" />
```

Comment: are you talking about Mozilla extensions (browser add-ons) or general HTML?

Comment: Talking about the L20N framework http://l20n.org/

Comment: oh sorry, missed the tag (:

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A normal translation (meaning you want to replace the content) is written like this:

```
<test "this is a translated text">
```

You can then translate attributes like this:

```
<test "this is a translated text" title:"this is the title">
```

In your case, you only want the attribute, so this will work:

```
<test placeholder:"this is a translated text">
```

The HTML should be

```
<input type="text" data-l10n-id="test" placeholder="" />
```

Comment: doesn't work for attributes like href, my-custom-attribute